# How to change the theme of CrystalReportViewer

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, reportviewer

I am using C# and I have changed the theme of my windows forms application and it works fine except for `CrystalReportViewers` the I have used.

I coundn t find a way how to change it and can anyone please let me know how to change the theme of `CrystalReportViewer`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the theme for a Crystal Report Viewer is only available in ASP.NET not WinForms.

See [this MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225513.aspx) for the available features and their applicable platforms.

Comment: At last I too could find info about asp.net only... But I was not sure whether it was correct. Thanks for the answer...